# What is the order of events in Docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Test case**

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  custom-image:
    build: ../custom-image-folder/
    volumes:
     - /var/www/my_host_app:/usr/share/custom-service/my_app
```

`Dockerfile` file of custom image:

```
FROM node:7.8.0-alpine
MAINTAINER DarckCrystale "xxx@xxx.xxx"

RUN ls -l /usr/share/custom-service/my_app/

CMD [ "node" ]
```

**Behavior observed**

- On building the Docker compose, `RUN ls -l /usr/share/custom-service/my_app/` throws an error:

  > Step 3/6 : RUN ls -l /usr/share/custom-service/my_app/
  >
  > ---> Running in 8a26523188f9
  >
  > **ls: /usr/share/custom-service/my_app/: No such file or directory**
  >
  > **ERROR**: Service 'custom-node' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ls -l /usr/share/custom-service/my_app/' returned a non-zero code: 1
- If I comment `RUN ls -l /usr/share/custom-service/my_app/`:

  - Building of the Docker compose works
  - Command `docker exec compose_custom-image_1 ls -l /usr/share/custom-service/my_app/` works:

    > -rw-rw-r--    1 node     node          3627 Mar  6 10:40 file.js
    >
    > -rw-rw-r--    1 node     node          1194 Mar 28 12:54 README.md
    >
    > drwxr-xr-x    6 node     node          4096 Mar 28 12:54 application

With this test case, I suppose that Docker mount the volume described in `docker-compose.yml` file AFTER building custom-image, explaining why in the Dockerfile we can't access to it.

**Question**

What is the order of events with Docker compose?
Is there somewhere a documentation explaining it?

Comment: This is the same behavior as when building the Dockerfile with `docker build`.  Volumes aren't mounted when building images, only when creating containers.

Comment: Do you know if there is an official post/page where the order of the complete behavior of a Docker build is detailed?

Like:
1/ read the docker-compose.yml
2/ get the first service in it
3/ build the service
....

Answer (score 4):

In docker compose (generally `docker run`) mounted volumes (`volumes` in compose and `-v` in docker run) are applied to the running container.

On the other hand the Dockerfile instructions like `RUN` are executed at build time.

That's why you get error if you build your first `Dockerfile`.

So this is what happens:

```
$ docker build -t custom-image .
$ docker run -v /var/www/my_host_app:/usr/share/custom-service/my_app custom-image
```

And compose also follows the exact same order (it's not possible otherwise).

Comment: That's not really answer to my question, which is more global: is there somewhere a detailed explanation of the order of events on the run on a Docker compose, not only for the volume creation?

Comment: I think you need to read a bit more on how "Docker" works in order to understand the compose. Everything that you provide for `build` section is done first always, because that's a requisite to running the container.

Comment: I understand, that was just an example. And for the extra_hosts statement? And for the environment statement?... I'm looking for some kind of documentation of how the thing is working in it's "core", not for particular examples, but for all.

Comment: I the original question you are cailming that `ls` command in Dockerfile fails which has nothing to do with compose. That's why I think you need to know a bit dipper about how Docker works. Read here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: The first question of my post is: `What is the order of events with Docker compose?`. Before, it's a supposition, not a question. Thank you for the links :)

Comment: @Boynux what is order in case of more than one services? Assuming there are two services and each one of them have different Dockerfile, will the sequence looks like Build1, Build2,  Run1, Run2  or, Build1, Run1, Build2, Run2  ?